# How to process a .ttl file of 3 attributes using rdflib (python 3.x)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, rdflib

I have a .ttl file which consists of 3 attributes.

Ex: `<http://dbpedia.org/resource/James_B._McLeran> <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> "James B. McLeran"@en .`

How can I parse and store these attributes using RDFlib?

```
Expected output: subject = <http://dbpedia.org/resource/James_B._McLeran>
                 predicate = <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label>
                 object = "James B. McLeran"@en .
```

Comment: Is there any pattern for the Input file ?

Comment: Well not really. I am working on the DBpedia dataset. Every line starts with the subject <http://..........> followed with a blank space then the predicate <http//........> followed with a blank space then the object "......."@language.  Additional examples : <http://dbpedia.org/resource/AccessibleComputing> <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> "AccessibleComputing"@en .
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/AfghanistanHistory> <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> "AfghanistanHistory"@en .

Answer (score 1):

```py
from rdflib import Graph

g = Graph()

g.parse("http://downloads.dbpedia.org/something.ttl", format="turtle")

for triple in g:
    print(
        """
        subject = {}
        predicate = {}
        object = {}
        """.format(*triple)
    )
```